# Параллельно или последовательно запускаются тесты на go с помощью библиотеки testify?

Tags: golang, testng

Есть группа тестов которые при каждом запуске имеют разный вариант. У меня есть догадка к тому что тесты запускаются параллельно и все зависит от очередности выполнения тестов. Может кто то работал с этой библиотекой и поможет. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека здесь не причем. Все зависит от того сколько у вас пакетов. Go запускает параллельно тесты пакетов, а вот уже внутри пакета тесты идут последовательно. Их так же можно распараллелить указав в тесте сигнал `t.Parallel()`